# How to disable movement to next line when comment a line in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut

My PhpStorm comment line command shortcut is `Ctrl+Q`. Everytime I press `Ctrl+Q` I get line commented, but caret moves to next line.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour and how?

Comment: As far as I'm aware that isn't configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. PhpStorm Macros built-in functionality helps with my needs.

This is my how-to: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435#comment=27-1834754

Answer (score 3):

It's not configurable.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Also check comments there for the reasons of current behaviour. I *personally* prefer current behaviour over what you are requesting.

Comment: I migrated to PhpStorm from Sublime so that's the question of habit :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible from PHPStorm 2021.2 as per the comment on YouTrack.

Steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Advanced Settings
3. Scroll to the Editor section
4. Uncheck the box for "Move caret down after Comment with Line Comment action"
5. Done!

YouTrack Comment:

> In 2021.2 this will be configurable (Settings | Advanced Settings | Editor | [ ] Move caret down after Comment with Line Comment action)

[YouTrack | Keep caret position when commenting code](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435/Keep-caret-position-when-commenting-code#focus=Comments-27-4883227.0-0)